# How to git push safely on intermittent internet connection?

Tags: git, github, push

<sub>Git newbie, pardon my ignorance</sub>

Besides being an excellent version control tool, I use Git for backing up my code safely to github servers.

Now I am moving to a remote location where internet is available intermittently i.e. once in a few days from a nearby town. How can I possibly do something like:-

zip the `.git` folder, carry it to internet cafe, unzip it and somehow ask github to read it and sync all my commit and branching history to server

---

P.S. I am currently not looking for advanced uses like merging and rebase, I mostly work alone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042470/can-i-copy-a-git-working-copy-onto-another-machine

Comment: You will need to take your computer because I doubt that a computer at an internet cafe will have git installed.